# org-mode inline collapsible sections

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm looking to get a collapsible section in the middle of a flow, is there a way to get something like it with org-mode? IE, to be able to collapse part of body called "sidetrack"?

```
* Installing xyz
make package1
make package2
  ** Sidetrack, get package3
     curl package3
     tar -xvf package3
make package3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question looks a lot like it's [in the FAQ](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#closing-outline-sections).

You're probably looking for [inlinetasks](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob;f=lisp/org-inlinetask.el;h=01f861e611aee4c24fcf7184ea191962be83be70;hb=HEAD), or simply list items (which also collapse with `TAB`) :

```
* Installing xyz
make package1
make package2
- Sidetrack, get package3
  curl package3
  tar -xvf package3
make package3
```

You don't need to put another bullet (in this case, a dash) for the item to end if you stop indenting and let your text be on column 0. If you want to indent it all, then indent the bullet, and the entry will consist of all that's indented more than the bullet. Details in [the Org manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html#fnd-18).